# Issues with css transition and background image

Tags: html, css, background-image, css-transitions

I am working on a website right now where a puppet is taking place when we hover the form 
My problem is : how can I fix and set the background image I have in order to appear when it is animated (and thus the padding increases) but not swipe from left to right?

Do you have any idea?

Best,

Here is the css code

```
 body .cf7-style.cf7-style-15648 {
  transition: all 1.5s;
}
.sent {
   background-image: url("http://www.site.fr/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/perverse-paul-serre.gif") !important ;
    background-position: right bottom;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  padding-right:205px !important;
}
.col.span_12.color-dark.left{
display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}  
form.wpcf7-form.demo.cf7-style.cf7-style-15648:hover{
padding-right: 205px;
  transition: all 0.6s ease-in-out;
}
form.wpcf7-form.demo.cf7-style.cf7-style-15648{}
body .cf7-style.cf7-style-15648{
 padding-right: 10px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 767px){
.col.span_12.color-dark.left{
  display: block;
}
  form.wpcf7-form.demo.cf7-style.cf7-style-15648{
     width:100%;
       border:none;
       padding-right:205px;
     }
  .col.span_12.color-dark.left{
     margin-left: 10px;
     }
  .vc_col-sm-7.wpb_column.column_container.col.no-padding.color-dark{
        display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-end;
}
}
```

Comment: Please include any relevant code in the question

Comment: Can you be more specific.

Comment: Thank you for answering. As it's a wordpress based website, it is hard to take apart some specific code. But here is the css related to the event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am taking a wild guess here as your question is not very clear but here goes...

On your form you have the following CSS

```
body .cf7-style.cf7-style-15648:hover {
    background-image: url(http://www.test.bonnetdejour.fr/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/paul-form-1.gif);
    background-position: right bottom;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

This is setting the `background-position` on hover. When you are not hovering on the form this will be using the default background position of:

```
background-position: left top;
```

If you set the background position on the element without hover I think it will do what you want.

```
body .cf7-style.cf7-style-15648{
    background-position: right bottom;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

body .cf7-style.cf7-style-15648:hover {
    background-image: url(http://www.test.bonnetdejour.fr/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/paul-form-1.gif);
}
```

Sorry if I have got it all wrong but this is my best guess as your question is unclear.

Comment: Great it worked ! Thank you so much